# JavaFX Split Menu Button Arrow Trigger Event

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `SplitMenuButton`, and I can't seem to find a way to trigger an event when the user clicks the arrow next to the button.

I would like the dropdown to fill with items from a database when the dropdown arrow is clicked.

I am not sure which event can do that, and I can not find any info on this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: register a listener with the [`showing` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html#showingProperty).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitMenuButton;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SplitMenuButtonTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        IntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        SplitMenuButton splitMenuButton = new SplitMenuButton();
        splitMenuButton.setText("Action");
        splitMenuButton.showingProperty().addListener((obs, wasShowing, isNowShowing) -> {
            if (isNowShowing) {
                int c = count.get() + 1;
                count.set(c);
                splitMenuButton.getItems().clear();
                for (int choice = 1; choice <= 3; choice++) {
                    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem("Choice "+choice+" (" + c + ")");
                    splitMenuButton.getItems().add(mi);
                }
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(null, splitMenuButton, null, null, null);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 350, 150));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Sort of as an aside, I'm not sure this is a really good idea. Database connections are typically long-running processes (i.e. long enough to be visually noticeable in a UI environment). If you run this on the FX Application Thread, then you're going to block the UI from doing anything while the data is retrieved, and that's also right at the moment the user has just tried to do something. Of course, if you run it as a background task, then the menu will popup with the previous data, and then later update once the data is downloaded. I would recommend finding a way to populate this before the user requests it.

Comment: The database is a local SQLite database where the data isn't transferred over a network. Basically it is a `select * from table` which will probably return less than 100 results

Answer (score 0):

The 'arrow' is just another button used to show the popup with the menu items.

One easy way of knowing if this arrow button is pressed is by listening to the showing property of the popup.

Once you know that the popup is showing up, you can add your items.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    SplitMenuButton m = new SplitMenuButton();
    m.showingProperty().addListener((ov,b,b1)->{
        if(b1){
            System.out.println("popup visible");
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("New Option");
            if(m.getItems().stream().noneMatch(i->i.getText().equals(menuItem.getText()))){
                menuItem.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("New Option added"));
                m.getItems().add(menuItem);
            }
        }
    });
    m.setText("Click the arrow ->");                
    m.getItems().add(new MenuItem("First option"));

    StackPane root = new StackPane(m);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```